# How to create non-capturing groups (How to apply `?` on combination of two sub expressions when using re.findall in python)?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, findall

I want to return all the words which start and end with letters or numbers. They may contain at most one period `.` OR hypen `-`in the word.
So, `ab.ab` is valid but `ab.` is not valid.

```
import re
reg = r"[\d\w]+([-.][\d\w]+)?"
s = "sample text"
print(re.findall(reg, s))
```

It is not working because of the parenthesis. How can I apply the `?` on combination of `[-.][\d\w]+`

Comment: Note: `\w` usually contains (is a superset of) `\d`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `ab.` is not valid and should not be matched and the period or the hyphen should not be at the start or at the end, you could match one or more times a digit or a character followed by an optional part that matches a dot or a hyphen followed by one or more times a digit or a character.

`(?<!\S)[a-zA-Z\d]+(?:[.-][a-zA-Z\d]+)?(?!\S)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0AmDYZ/1)

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)` Negative lookbehind to assert that what is on the left is not a non whitespace character
- `[a-zA-Z\d]+` Match one or more times a lower/uppercase character or a digit
- `(?:[.-][a-zA-Z\d]+)?` An optional non capturing group that would match a dot or a hypen followed by or more times a lower/uppercase character or a digit
- `(?!\S` Negative lookahead that asserts that what is on the right is not a non whitespace character.

[Python demo](http://rextester.com/FGCFI75424)

Comment: why the lookarounds?

Comment: Else it would match ab in `ab.`

Comment: This one should be the correct answer, +1 for it.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, don't make the group capturing. Use `(?:pattern)` instead of `(pattern)`:

```
import re
reg = r"[\d\w]+(?:[-.][\d\w]+)?"
s = "sample text"
print(re.findall(reg, s))
```

Output:

```
['sample', 'text']
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it a non-capturing group instead, so that there won't be any capturing groups, which will ensure that the full match is grabbed by `re.findall`:

```
reg = r"[\d\w]+(?:[-.][\d\w]+)?"
```